# Fluent Entity Framework Mapping

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, fluent-interface

Is there any way to perform Fluent EF Mapping like Fluent NHibernate for NHibernate ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entity Framework v4.0 introduces the Code Only concept which is really close to Fluent NHibernate. More information is available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/11/12/updated-feature-ctp-walkthrough-code-only-for-entity-framework.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/10/12/code-only-further-enhancements.aspx) in the ADO.NET team blog