# Fluent mapping verification for Entity Framework 4

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef4-code-only

*Note: This is a follow-up question for [this previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845688/fluent-entity-framework-mapping).*

Inspired by [this blog post](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2008/06/19/working-faster-and-fewer-mapping-errors-with-nhibernate/), I'm trying to construct a fluent way to test my EF4 Code-Only mappings. However, I'm stuck almost instantly...

To be able to implement this, I also need to implement the `CheckProperty` method, and I'm quite unsure on how to save the parameters in the `PersistenceSpecification` class, and how to use them in `VerifyTheMappings`.

Also, I'd like to write tests for this class, but I'm not at all sure on how to accomplish that. What do I test? And how?

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:** I've taken a look at the implementation in Fluent NHibernate's source code, and it seems like it would be quite easy to just take the source and adapt it to Entity Framework. However, I can't find anything about modifying and using *parts* of the source in the [BSD licence](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/raw/master/LICENSE.txt). Would copy-pasting their code into my project, and changing whatever I want to suit my needs, be legal for non-commercial private or open source projects? Would it be for commercial projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to suggest looking at how FluentNH does this, until I got to your *update*. Anyway, you're already investigating that approach.

As to the portion of your question regarding the BSD license, I'd say the relevant part of the license is this: *Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met: [conditions follow]*.

From my reading of that line, you can modify (which would include *the removal of any code* not relevant to your use cases) the code however you wish, and redistribute it as long as you meet the author's conditions.

Since there are no qualifications on how you may use or redistribute the code or binaries, then you are free to do that however you wish, for any and all applications.

[Here](http://pthree.org/2007/08/08/bsd-license-explained-in-layman-terms/) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#3-clause_license_.28.22New_BSD_License.22_or_.22Modified_BSD_License.22.29) are descriptions of the license in layman's terms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always writing simple set of integration tests for each entity. Tests are persisting, selecting, updating and deleting entity. I thing there is no better and easier way to test your mapping and other features of the model (like cascade deletes).

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to accomplish too. However, I don't want to have to repeat that code for every project - instead, I want to construct a fluent interface like that of Fluent NHibernate, but targeting EF4 Code-Only.